# Remi Repo Mysql Server Not Starting

Tags: mysql, centos, yum, strace

Executing the command to start the mysql service fails to start the mysql server.

```
[root@localhost]# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Ran an strace on it

I have mysql mysql-server php php-mysql all from remi for the latest centos available versions

Here is my my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I think the strace is now linked in a comment

here is a dump of mysql_safe

```
[root@localhost var]# mysqld_safe
110209 15:11:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
110209 15:11:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
110209 15:11:52 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19399737/strace.output

Comment: [root@localhost var]# rpm -V mysql
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz
S.5.....  d /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz

Answer (score 1):

http://almamunbd.blogspot.com/2010/10/only-480-error-messages-but-it-should.html
is the solution to this problem pass the word on

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start `mysqld_safe` right from a root console to check its output?

Comment: 110209 15:11:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
    110209 15:11:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
    110209 15:11:52 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
is what i get from that

Comment: OK, if `/var/log/mysqld.log` is not empty, could you please also post last 10-20 lines from there (you can use `tail -n 10 /var/log/mysqld.log`)

Comment: -[Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Unknown error 1146
-[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
-InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
-InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
-InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 405409
-[ERROR] Aborting
-InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
-InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 405409
-[Note]
-mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

Comment: Apparently you should run `mysql_upgrade`

Comment: cant run it without the daemon working
[root@localhost var]# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Comment: Well, it looks like mysql.plugin error is unrelated. It should start w/o this table. Something is wrong with InnoDB. Probably you should delete `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*` files then try to start it again. Don't forget to make a backup of `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*` before removal.

Comment: tried that, cut and paste them to the desktop. No start same error when using [root@localhost var]# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

Comment: i took that whole folder out and made mysql recreate the starting tables but it gives an error Initializing MySQL database:  Installing MySQL system tables...
110209 15:58:37 [ERROR] Error message file '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys' had only 480 error messages,
but it should contain at least 641 error messages.
Check that the above file is the right version for this program!
110209 15:58:37 [ERROR] Aborting

Answer (score 0):

What does /var/log/mysqld.log have to say?

Comment: how do you want me to post this to you the file is rather large

Comment: Last 10 lines should be OK

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19399737/mysqld.log

Comment: Which mysql-libs do you have? rpm -qa | grep mysql